# How to prevent kube-dns from forwarding request to 8.8.8.8:53

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, kube-dns, skydns

How can I prevent kube-dns from forwarding request to Google's name servers (8.8.8.8:53 and 8.8.4.4:53)?
I just want to launch pods only for internal use, which means containers in pods are not supposed to connect to the outside at all.
When a Zookeeper client connects to a Zookeeper server using hostname (e.g. zkCli.sh -server zk-1.zk-headless), it takes 10 seconds for the client to change its state from [Connecting] to [Connected].
The reason I suspect kube-dns is that, with pods' IP address, the client gets connected instantly.
When I take a look at the log of kube-dns, I found the following two lines:

```
07:25:35:170773       1 logs.go:41] skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 10.244.0.13:43455->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout"
07:25:39:172847       1 logs.go:41] skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 10.244.0.13:42388->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout"
```

It was around 07:25:30 when the client starts to connect to the server.

I'm running Kubernetes on a private cluster where internal servers are communicating to internet via http_proxy/https_proxy, which means I cannot connect to 8.8.8.8 for name resolution, AFAIK.

I found the followings from https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns:

- The default value of an environmental variable named **SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS** is **"8.8.8.8:53,8.8.4.4:53"**
- I could achieve my purpose by setting **no_rec** to **true**

I've been initiating Kubernetes using kubeadm and I couldn't find a way to modify the environmental variable and set the property value of skydns.

How can I prevent kube-dns from forwarding request to the outside of an internal Kubernetes cluster which is deployed by kubeadm?

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl get deploy --namespace=kube-system kube-dns -o yaml` ? It's either configured with the `-nameserver` flag or the `SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS` environment variable.

Comment: I cannot find neither -nameserver flag nor SKYDNS_NAMESERVERS env from kube get deployments.

Comment: It seems like the following is used to create a kube-dns container : 
- args:
        - --domain=cluster.local
        - --dns-port=10053
        - --config-map=kube-dns
        - --v=2
        env:
        - name: PROMETHEUS_PORT
          value: "10055"
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64:1.9
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

Comment: There's no ConfigMap object called kube-dns, and kube-dns container says in log that it cannot find Configmap named kube-system:kube-dns with the following log message: dns.go:190] Error getting initial ConfigMap: configmaps "kube-dns" not found, starting with default values.

Comment: Did this issue get resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to completely prevent the `kube-dns` addon from forwarding requests. There certainly isn't an option directly in `kubeadm` for that.

Your best bet is to edit the `kube-dns` `Deployment` (e.g. `kubectl edit -n kube-system deploy kube-dns`) yourself after kubeadmin has started the cluster and change things to work for you.

You may want to try changing the upstream nameserver to something other than 8.8.8.8 that *is* accessible by the cluster. You should be able to do that by adding `--nameservers=x.x.x.x` to the `args` for the `kubedns` container.